# Dynamically render a pageblock title

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce, dynamic-vf-component

I am wondering if there's a way to dynamically render the title in the pageblock- something like this:

```
<apex:pageblock title="{!account.name}"> </apex:pageblock>
```

From the visualforce components documentation, it doesn't seem like it's something do-able. It seems to like it's a simple thing that salesforce should be able to do.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is do-able. The [expression language](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_display_field_values.htm) works AFAIK pretty much everywhere including the **title** attribute in your example. The documentation examples typically show only the most basic use.

Comment: Hi Keith, you are right. I believe my issue emanated from the fact that I my controller is a custom controller but I typed it in as if I was using a standard controller. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it in practice, but you might be able to do something with an [apex:facet](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_facet.htm).

E.g. where `showTitle` is a property in the controller that returns a boolean indicating if the title should be rendered.

```
<apex:pageblock>
     <apex:facet name="header">
         <apex:outputText value="{!account.name}" rendered="{!showTitle}" />
     </apex:facet>
</apex:pageblock>
```

From the [title documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlock.htm):

> Note that if a header facet is included in the body of the pageBlock component, its value overrides this [the title] attribute.

Failing that, just wrap `account.name` in another controller property or method and bind to that instead. The new property or method could return null or an empty string if it should be hidden.

Comment: Only header and footer facets are documented for apex:pageBlock.

Comment: @KeithC Whoops, yes. I've fixed the facet name to be "header" and added the documentation that it overrides the title attribute.

Comment: Cool. Didn't realize you could add content (presumably made of multiple elements if needed) to a apex:pageblock that way.

Comment: I've used it to style the header for an apex:pageBlockSection in the past. Haven't tried to make it optionally disappear yet.